# Using DirectShow CaptureNet to add audio to avi

Tags: directshow, webcam, video-capture, audio-recording, directshow.net

Hi I am using the CaptureNet application out of the box from this codeproject source:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshownet.aspx

What I'm trying to do is also capture audio from the mic in this whilst video from my webcam is being saved to an AVi file, I want to interleave audio into the same file. Currently the one described that comes with just video capture. I'm fairly new to this, I have managed to capture audio separatly as a WAV file but no idea where to start to save both video and audio into the same AVI file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect audio stream to the second input pin of AVI Mux filter which is created after you connect video stream to the first input pin.